# Can't find anything using simplHtmlDom

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

On my host i scrape some differents website and everything was ok until yesterday.
After change the host server they don't work anymore.
This is the situation:
I can get whole html of the page using `simpleHtmlDom` and `Curl` ,but cant fetch anything using `find` on it.

```
$str = file_get_contents($url);
$html = str_get_html($str);

if (!empty($html)) {
    echo "html is not null";
    if( $html->find('div[class="header"]' , 0)){
        echo "found";
    }
}
```

result:

```
html is not null
```

I checked it on different urls and different websites and result is same! Any suggestion?

Edit:

-tried to different way to get html:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
$str = curl_exec($curl);

$html = str_get_html($str);
```

and

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
```

and

```
$html = new simple_html_dom(); 
$html->load($url);
```

result was same.

-Send mail to my hosting support and ask about any change on configuration that makes this happend. They said they changed the server of my host.

- before face the problem, i  didn't make any change on my scripts.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What does "change the host server" mean? Why not simply rollback the change, if that affects your application?

Comment: @Zima did you inspect $html's content to check if you are actually supposed to get a match?

Comment: @nitrin0 Yes ofcourse,i posted just an example but i tried many different tags that are available in content (on different websites and urls)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Have you even tried to check **why** this fails? Maybe the markup changed?

Comment: @nico-haase I checked different tags on different websites and urls, i mean cant get the static content of the page using "find" command.I posted my problem because I don't know why its happend!

Comment: @Zima i meant the actual value in the `$html` variable, not what you see on a target uri. Like nico-haase said this might simply be a markup change or something preventing you from reading the target uri. It's a good place to start in order to debug this issue.

Comment: **Dump** `$html` to inspect the markup, don't guess what it should contain

Comment: nico-haase @nitrin0 Thank you so much guys.yes I did.Let me to check them again and  let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the hosting support, changing PHP version to 7.2 was the solution.Now all my scripts work perfectly.